# Asp.net Get JQuery Session

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, session

I have a JQuery that store value in Session
Here is my Code

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    store.set('MySession', 'SessionValue')
});
```

Now I want to get that session using Asp.net
Here is my code

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>");
    Response.Write("alert('Your Session: " + Session["MySession"].ToString()+ "');");
    Response.Write("</script>");
}
```

And When I try to run it and error exception was caught:
NullReferenceException was caught.
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: "JQuery that store value in Session"? Whoever up-voted the question please explain what if relationship between browser side code and ASP.Net server side `Session`.

Comment: That means there is no way to get the jquery session using asp.net?

Comment: what is store? Looks like you might be using some plugin that you have not defined. store is not a javascript or jquery object.

Comment: I found this library jquery.cookie.js somewhere in the net.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that this jQuery session you speak of is the HTML5 Session Storage?

If so, then you can't access it from your ASP.NET code-behind. ASP.NET's Session is a completely different thing.

This article on MSDN provides more information on what is ASP.NET's session: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx

EDIT: So your "jQuery session" is simply a library for storing variables. You can't access a client-side object from the server-side without actually sending it over the wire. The server does not have a direct access to what lives in the browser.